# How to think like a Computer Scientist exercise

Tags: python, python-2.7, nonetype

So as the title hopefully suggest, this is for an example in said book.
I'm still new to programming and having difficulty debugging. With that said any criticism is welcomed, specially if it shows a more efficient way of coding; just keep in mind that I'm still new so there's a good chance i might not know what you're referring to if you toss me a new built-in function or something.

So the point of this exercise is to write a function, giving it three arguments, to determine if those three arguments form a triangle. Here's my code:

```
def is_triangle(a,b,c):
    num_list = [a,b,c]
    biggest = max(num_list)
    other_two = num_list.remove(biggest)
    sum_of_two = sum(other_two)

    if sum_of_two > biggest:
        print 'Congrats, %d, %d, and %d form a triangle!' % (a,b,c)
    elif sum_of_two == biggest:
        print 'That forms a degenerate triangle!'
    else:
        print 'That does\'t make any sort triangle... >:['


def sides():
    side1 = raw_input('Please input side numero Juan: ')
    side2 = raw_input('Now side two: ')
    side3 = raw_input('...aaaannnd three: ')
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'Thanks >:]'
    side1 = int(side1)
    side2 = int(side2)
    side3 = int(side3)
    is_triangle(side1,side2,side3)

sides()
```

Whenever i run it, however, i get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:/Python/is_triangle.py", line 27, in <module>
    sides()
  File "A:/Python/is_triangle.py", line 25, in sides
    is_triangle(side1,side2,side3)
  File "A:/Python/is_triangle.py", line 5, in is_triangle
    sum_of_two = sum(other_two)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

My guess is the sum_of_two line but i don't know what's wrong with it. Could someone help me debug this?

I spend a good hour rewriting it with out the built_in function (in various ways, bunch of `or`s everywhere). But it looked terrible and I'd rather learn to write this way.

Comment: `list.remove()` removes the first occurrence of a value, so the case where the numbers are `(5, 5, 2)` shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: +1 for giving us the full code and error, by the way.

Comment: @steveha, gnibbler: well what do you know, thanks. I don't use that function often. :)

Comment: @GregHewgill: what difference does that(two sides being equal) make (as per the code)?

Comment: @0xc0de: My original (now deleted) comment was based on a misunderstanding of what `.remove()` does.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the fact that `remove` modifies the underlying list - it doesn't return a new list. Change it to:

```
num_list.remove(biggest)
sum_of_two = sum(num_list)
```

To see exactly why this happens, try the following in IDLE:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> x.remove(1)
>>> x
[2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: YES! Thank you! Learned something new already today. I think the indentations messed up when i pasted my code here, but thanks everyone else for their input.

Answer (score 2):

Since`num_list.remove(biggest)` returns `None`, Consider this instead

```
other1, other2, biggest = sorted(num_list)
sum_of_two = other1 + other2
```

It looks like the `if` block needs to be indented too

```
def is_triangle(a, b, c):
    num_list = [a, b, c]
    other1, other2, biggest = sorted(num_list)
    sum_of_two = other1 + other2

    if sum_of_two > biggest:
        print 'Congrats, %d, %d, and %d form a triangle!' % (a,b,c)
    elif sum_of_two == biggest:
        print 'That forms a degenerate triangle!'
    else:
        print 'That does\'t make any sort triangle... >:['
```

Comment: Nice, forgot i could do this ass well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You just made a very common mistake, a simple one.  In Python, when a function causes a change in a data structure, it does not return the changed structure.  Usually it returns `None`.  If the function gets a new data structure or new value, it returns it.

So, `str.lower()` doesn't actually change a string; it returns a new string where the characters are lower-case.  If you have some list named `lst` and you run `sorted(lst)`, it doesn't change the list; it returns a new list that is sorted.  But `lst.sort()` sorts the list in-place, so it doesn't return a reference to the list; it returns `None`.

In the comments below, @lvc pointed out that `list.pop()` removes a value from a list and returns the value.  So, this is an example of a function that changes a data structure and returns something other than `None`, but it still definitely does not return a reference to the changed data structure.

The `list.remove()` function changes a list, and it returns `None`.  All you need to do is change your function to use the same list for everything: first use the list to find the max, then remove the max value from the list, then pass the list to `sum()`.

The reason Python does things this way is to obey the "Command/Query Separation" principle.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation

Comment: +1 for the explanation of *why* `remove` returns `None`, although this is not true in *every* case - especially relevant here is `list.pop` with an argument, which behaves almost exactly the way the OP expected `list.remove` to (returning what was removed, rather than what is left).

Comment: @lvc, `list.pop()` follows the Command/Query Separation" rule because it doesn't return the thing that was modified (the list).  It returns the value pulled from the list.  The original code assumed that `list.remove()` would return the modified list; it doesn't, and neither does `list.pop()`.

Comment: @lvc, I think you raise a larger point that is correct: my explanation was oversimplified.  I said that Python functions that mutate data structures always return `None`, clearly not true as your `list.pop()` example shows.  I'll edit the answer to clarify a bit.  Thank you.